# Category Template: Need to display different content on first page of archives

Tags: posts, categories, templates, conditional-tags

So my issue is that I need to create two versions of a category.php template. Now, I know very well that if I want to display posts from just one category, I duplicate category.php and call it category-xx.php for the slug or ID number. Great. Got that.

The problem is the client wants it where on the first page of posts, only 4 posts appear. 6 on all subsequent pages. Worse, she wants a div with additional content to appear above the posts but only on the first page. So http://www.yoursite.com/category/whatever/page/2/ and /page/3/ look different than http://www.yoursite.com/category/whatever/.

Now I know I could use conditional comments like is_page() to specify a certain page to display let's say, a certain div. But how would I do it in this sense? Can I do it? There must be some kind of if...else statement that'll make this work.

Comment: Hey, did you get any solution>? I am still looking for good solution to this problem i have with woo-commerce and elementor based custom page.  I just want to show it on first page and not other pages.

Answer (score 2):

`get_query_var('paged')` will show you pagination information. The code below will show only on first page of archive

```
if(get_query_var('paged') == 1){
    //run extra code    
}
```

Comment: Works in informational way, but getting non-consistent amount of posts per page correcty is waaay more convoluted. :(

Comment: I actually had the same problem, but since WordPress shows the first page not as `../page/1` but simply as `../`, and `get_query_var` returned 0 on this page, while 2,3,... on all the later pages, I at the end used `if (get_query_var('paged') == 0){ /* do first page thing*/}`